# Setting the preferences in SIlverlight PrintDocument

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, printdocument

I'm using PrintDocument in Silverlight. I'm printing the Silverlight DataGrid in Silverlight page. When I'm printing it only half of the DataGrid is getting printed....so Can I set the preferences for PrintDocument anywhere. I would like to print it as a Landscape type. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a means to indicate that the printer should print in a landscape mode.

However the `PrintPageEventArgs` has a `PrintableArea` property from which you can discover the current aspect of the page.  Using this you could apply a `RenderTransform` (or you might need a `LayoutTransform`) to rotate your content 90 degrees.

Comment: Hi,

   Why should we rotate it to 90 degree??? how come that will solve the problem??